# Quick close case button fails to trigger workflow

Tags: javascript, custom-button, case, flow

I created a quick close case custom button that was working fine.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case");
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
caseObj.Status = 'Closed';
var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);
if (result[0].success=='false') {
     alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
     location.reload(true);
}
```

But I have added new reporting fields that are populated with a workflow/process, and now the button will not work.

Error that is given:

> The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. 
> A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 3014B0000008Onc. 
>  Contact your administrator for help.

How can I have my button and flows work together?

Comment: Are there any required fields or validation rules that are preventing the record form being saved? The visual workflows and process builder does not show proper error messages even if there are valid validations that prevent the record from being saved.